# Asp Page Connection string Error,

Tags: visual-studio-2012, vbscript, asp-classic, sql-server-2014, adodb

> 0x800a0e7d - ADODB.Recordset: The connection cannot be used to perform
>   this operation. It is either closed or invalid in this context.

I am getting this  error while running my asp page

```
 Set ConnectionString = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
 ConnectionString.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1; Password=pass@123;User            ID=sa;Initial Catalog=USERDB;  Data Source=SQL\MSSQLSERVER2014;" 

 Dim rs
 strSQL = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username= 'test' AND Password='test123'
        rs.Open strSQL, ConnectionString
```

I am using VS 2012 and SQL Server 2014, and I am running through IIS.

Comment: Is the typo in `strSQL` an accident? Missing ending double quote *(`"`)* on line 5.

Comment: So, did you find what was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```vb
'declare the variables 
Dim Conn 
Dim rs 
Dim strSQL

'declare the SQL statement that will query the database
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username= 'test' AND Password='test123'"

'create an instance of the ADO connection and recordset objects
Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset") 

'open the connection to the database
Conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=pass@123;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=USERDB;Data Source=SQL\MSSQLSERVER2014;"

'Open the recordset object executing the SQL statement and return records
rs.Open strSQL, Conn

...

'close the connection and recordset objects to free up resources
rs.Close
Set rs = nothing
Conn.Close
Set Conn = nothing
```

Comment: They just aren't terminating the connection string correctly missing end `"`. It doesn't need you to refactor the code, it would have worked as is with the typo corrected. Plus if you are going to refactor it, at least point them to parametrised queries *(of which there are 100s of samples on this site)*.

Comment: @Lankymart you mean missing " in query string? ConnectionString looks ok.

Comment: I meant the SQL string *(`strSQL`)*, it's not terminated properly *(line 5)* in the question, missing ending double quote *(`"`)*.